# Make Docker container use newest version of Python installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip, dockerfile

I have a couple of Python modules that I use inside my Docker container and they require a higher version of Python that what's being used. I install Python and install the modules using:

```
RUN apt-get update || : && apt-get install python3 -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
COPY requirements.txt /project
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Expecting I would be using the latest version of Python in my Docker container but when I go into it's shell and run `python3 --version` is comes as `3.4.2` which is incredibly old for my program. How do I make the default Python to be the latest I installed above without messing over the System-level python?

The image runtime I'm using for the Docker container is: `node:9-slim`

Comment: maybe install outside apt-get: `https://www.python.org/ftp/python/`

Comment: @anon01 sorry, forgot to mention that, I've tried that too

Comment: The first step might be using a newer Node than 9! In general odd versions shouldn't be used in prod anyway, the even ones get LTS support.

Comment: first you should check if it can install newer version - i.e. `apt search python3.9` - and install it using `python3.9` instead of `python3` in `apt-get install python3.9 -y`. And later you can run it as `python3.9 script.py` instead of `python3 script.py`. BTW: You should also install `python3.9-pip` and run `pip3.9` instead of `pip3` (or use `python3.9 -m pip install ...`)

Comment: BTW: if system uses `3.4.2` as `python3` then changing it may sometimes crush system so better don't change `python3` but use `python3.9` to run code.

Comment: @furas I installed python3.9, tried running the code inside the docker container manually using the shell and it still cannot find python3.9 `bash: python3.9: command not found`

Comment: maybe this distribution doesn't have `3.9` but only `3.8` or `3.7`. And if it has only 3.4 then you will have to install source code and compile it. Maybe it will be simpler to use docker image with `Python3.9` and install `node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can find a prebuilt python3.9 package on a debian 8 distribution as your environment is pretty old.

The only solution is you build the python3.9 out from [source code](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/) in your base container. A full workable Dockerfile as next:

```
FROM node:9-slim

RUN apt update; \
apt install -y build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev; \
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.7/Python-3.9.7.tgz; \
tar -zxvf Python-3.9.7.tgz; \
cd Python-3.9.7; \
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3; \
make && make install; \
ln -sf /usr/local/python3/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3; \
ln -sf /usr/local/python3/bin/pip3.9 /usr/bin/pip3
```

**Verify it:**

```
$ docker build -t myimage:1 .
$ docker run --rm -it myimage:1 python3 --version
Python 3.9.7
$ docker run --rm -it myimage:1 pip3 --version
pip 21.2.3 from /usr/local/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```